# two and more digit output not working in even/odd filter in python

Tags: python

```
def even_odd_filter(oe):
    odd_list = []
    even_list = []
    total = []
    for i in oe:
        i = int(i)
        if i % 2 == 0:
            even_list.extend(str(i))
        else:
            odd_list.extend(str(i))

    total = [even_list, odd_list]
    print("Even list : ", even_list)
    print("Odd list : ", odd_list)
    return total
```

userinput = input("Enter number by comma  : ").split(",")
print(even_odd_filter(userinput))

Comment: Fix the indentations in your code

Comment: "not working" is not a description. The title is also not a description.

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar  oh change extend to append    solved  thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `extend` to `append` will solve it

```
def even_odd_filter(oe):
    odd_list = []
    even_list = []
    total = []
    for i in oe:
        i = int(i)
        if i % 2 == 0:
            even_list.append(i)
        else:
            odd_list.append(i)
    total = [even_list, odd_list]
    print("Even list : ", even_list)
    print("Odd list : ", odd_list)
    return total
userinput = input("Enter number by comma : ").split(",")
print(even_odd_filter(userinput))
```

Output:

```
Enter number by comma : 1,12,13,15,14
Even list :  ['12', '14']
Odd list :  ['1', '13', '15']
[['12', '14'], ['1', '13', '15']]
```